# MongoDB consumes all memory(RAM)

Tags: mongodb, bulkinsert

I use MongoDB 3.2, WiredTiger engine. I am trying to use batch inserts on 10K records, the size of one record about kb. All great, but 60-70 million such records memory ends. Mongo is limited cache in 3GB, but the memory is consumed by memory map files collections and indexes. After some time Mongo CPU load at 100% and stops receiving data. OS: Windows 7. What am I doing wrong? :)

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include your code?

Comment: https://blog.clevertap.com/sleepless-nights-with-mongodb-wiredtiger-and-our-return-to-mmapv1/ :D

Comment: oof, that sounds brutal

Comment: @Alexey Having exactly same issue. From time to time we have lot of imports running which ends up by adding several millions records in MongoDB. Cache is limited as well, but it still uses ton of memory. Memory is released after restarting mongo but that does not help a lot having in mind that I cannot restart it all the time during production. Did you have any luck with this?